# How to query directly from a kafka topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've looked into [Interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) and [KSQL](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/concepts/ksql-architecture.html) but I can't seem to figure out if querying for a specific record(s) based on key is possible.

Say I have a record in a topic as shown:

```
{
  key: 12314,
  value: 
    {
       id: "1",
       name: "bob"
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to search for key 12314 in a topic? Also does KSQL and interactive queries consume the entire topic to do queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your value is valid JSON (i.e. the field names are also quoted) then you can do this easily with KSQL/ksqlDB:

Examine the Kafka topic in ksqlDB:

```
ksql> PRINT test3;
Format:JSON
1/9/20 12:11:35 PM UTC , 12314 , {"id": "1", "name": "bob"    }
```

Declare the stream:

```sql
ksql> CREATE STREAM FOO (ID VARCHAR, NAME VARCHAR) 
        WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test3',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

Filter the stream as data arrives

```sql
ksql> SELECT ROWKEY, ID, NAME FROM FOO WHERE ROWKEY='12314' EMIT CHANGES;
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|ROWKEY                      |ID                          |NAME                        |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|12314                       |1                           |bob                         |
```

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 1):

Everyone always forgets to add that you can use an interactive query if the underlying dataset is small and can be materialized.

For example, you cannot efficiently find a message by key in a huge topic. At least I cannot find such a way

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with interactive queries.

You can create a kafka stream to read the input topic and generate a state store ( in memory/rocksdb and synchronize with kafka ).

This state store is queryable by key ( ReadOnlyKeyValueStore ).

You have multiples examples in the official documentation: 
https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html